# Angular cli import assets from other package

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli

I have two angular-cli projects, one for core components and the second for my application.

In the core project, I have assets like fonts. In my `style.scss` file I am importing the font like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansregular';
    src: url('/src/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

When I am installing the core package in my main application and importing `style.scss` like this:

```
@import '~app-core/src/styles.scss';
```

I am getting the error:

> Cannot find
>   http://localhost:9999/src/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the relative url

such as:

```
src: url('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
```

The below cod works for me.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto';
    src: url('../assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting Can't resolve '../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff'